# Why does Gmail no longer offer the 'Send through Gmail option' for aliases?

Tags: gmail, smtp

In the past, I could add any email address that I own via **Settings → Accounts → Add another email address you own**.  [I document this on my blog](http://www.ibeck.com/chris/?p=105).  On that wzard, there were 2 options:

[image: Gmail Add Email Wizard, Page 2]

But now it only lets you specify the SMTP server directly and it doesn't accept the standard settings of `smtp.gmail.com`

[image]

Did they change policies?  Or am I missing something here?  I tried this on two different accounts.

Comment: The interesting part is that they still don't support separate single-purpose-only passwords for smtp at gmail.com themselves (unless you go into a separate and non-related two-factor auth), so, if this policy of theirs were to be implemented by example.su, requiring the smtp password of gmail.com, and giving access to the whole Google Account of the user, just for smtp, how would they feel?

Really bad move, Google.  Or at least they could start letting people have single-purpose-only passwords, like for outgoing mail only.

Comment: yeah, I think we're talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google is getting out of the business of sending email using domains that it does not administer, because it stands in the way of implementing rules that reduce spoofed email, such as [DMARC](http://www.dmarc.org/).  This also has the side effect of encouraging customers to host their email domains with Google.

Google is grandfathering existing email address configurations, but they are not allowing new email addresses to be added.

Yahoo did something similar when they [activated DMARC enforcement](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/yahoo-dmarc-policy-sln24050.html).  This made it harder to send email from mailing lists claiming to come from @yahoo.com, @aol.com, etc. .  [AOL soon followed suit](http://postmaster-blog.aol.com/2014/04/22/aol-mail-updates-dmarc-policy-to-reject/). See [this PCWorld article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2141120/yahoo-email-antispoofing-policy-breaks-mailing-lists.html) for more on the fallout and reasoning.

Update: There was no formal Google announcement about this policy change, but [this support thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/GyeMcHv1U-g%5B1-25-false%5D) has an answer from a Google employee.

Update 2015-03-17: Google appears to have restored this functionality, but only by configuring Gmail to use the authorized SMTP server for the domain.  In this configuration, Gmail is acting solely as an email client, submitting your emails to the server that is the MTA for the domain. This also means that Gmail has to store your SMTP password in plain text in order to pass it along to the server.

Comment: Very interesting.  Are there any official postings from Gmail to this effect.  I found https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580?hl=en but none that explicity connect the dots between my question and Gmail's DMARC policy.

Comment: In Gmail's case, the change isn't directly about DMARC, but rather a way to avoid violating other domains' DMARC policies.  I'm still searching for the original announcement, but setup requirements have changed here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: Concur.  Here is a thread (see wdurham's Aug 7 explanation) of some other puzzled users trying to make sense of this change. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/QNMgV2r5X4A